# Dot product identity $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos(\alpha)$ true for $a,b \in R^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b$ be vectors from $R^\infty$. Where $\sum a_ib_i$, $\sum a_i^2$ and $\sum b_i^2$ are convergent. Can I still use the following identity for the dot product?

$$a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos(\alpha)$$

Where $\alpha$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? Is this your definition of it, or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: It's true that $-1 \le \frac{a\cdot b}{|a|\,|b|} \le 1$, so you can define the angle as arc-cosine of this fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the absolute convergence of $\sum a_ib_i$ already follows from that of $\sum a_i^2$ and $\sum  b_i^2$, so you need not assume it separately. And yes, you could use this identity for the dot product. It will define the angle $\alpha$ between the vectors $a_i$ and $b_i$ in a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you alot :D. I will accept you question tomorrow, as i will got to sleep now :D.

Comment: so will I. good night :)